# Windows hosts and server alias do not work

Tags: windows, alias, server, hosts

I have 2 domains that are on 2 servers. (migration)

I switched to the new one in hosts file.

Records in hosts:
1.2.3.4 domain.com
1.2.3.4 alias.eu //alias is just an alias without redirect

I can ping domain.com -> 1.2.3.4 and I can open it in browser and it works.
I can ping alias.eu -> 1.2.3.4 but when I open it in a browser I get 403 forbidden.

Is it possible to have it like that? Or I have to change DNS on servers?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the question, is your web server at 1.2.3.4 responding with the same site to both hostnames ?

Comment: If I call domain.com it works normally. If I call alias.eu there is an alias to domain.com.

Comment: So you can see the 403 in your web server's log?

Comment: I dont have access to server log.

Comment: But you are sure it is configured to respond to requests for alias.eu hostname ?

Comment: I am because it can be seen in the `domain.com` that it has an alias and `alias.eu` is set to be an alias for `domain.com`.